# correct way to write the path to include an image

Tags: css

Is there a difference between `<img src="skins/monobook/ask_button.gif"/>`
and `<img src="/skins/monobook/ask_button.gif"/>`?

The image is not showing on my site. When I remove the / in inspect element it shows but if I edit the file and remove the / and reload the page it considers it as thought the / is there. Why?

I'm in a file extension/file.php and the image is in the file /skins/monobook/ask_button.gif how do I set it up for the correct path?

Comment: is the skins folder also in the extension folder? If not you need to add ../ before the skins folder.

Comment: What is the relationship between the `extension/` and the `skins/` folder?

Answer (score 1):

the file is in **extension/file.php** so you need to come back once and go to the sibling path to reach **skins** directory so try this..

```
<img src="../skins/monobook/ask_button.gif"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `skins/monobook/ask_button.gif` and `/skins/monobook/ask_button.gif` is that the former is a relative file path (hence will look for the folder at the same level of the file) while the latter is an absolute file path (hence will look for the directory at the web root, typically `/www/` of an Apache server for example).

If you want to traverse directories using relative file paths, you should use `../`, which will move one directory upwards (i.e. parent directory). You can combine that to traverse as many levels as you want, e.g. `../../` will move two directories upwards.

---

For example, if your directory tree looks like this:

```
www/
+---extension/
+---+---file.php
+---skin/
+---+---monobook/
+---+---+---ask_button.gif
```

Then you should use `../skin/monobook/ask_button.gif`, because you will have to navigate one level up from `file.php` and then search for the `skin/` folder on the same level.

---

However, if your directory tree looks like this:

```
www/
+---extension/
+---+---file.php
+---+---skin/
+---+---+---monobook/
+---+---+---+---ask_button.gif
```

Then `skin/` is in the same level as `file.php`, so to call the image from the file you will need to use the relative path of `./skin/monobook/ask_button.gif` or simply `skin/monobook/ask_button.gif`.

---

p/s: There is a [short article out there](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) succinctly describing relative file paths in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
<img src="~/skins/monobook/ask_button.gif"/>
```

Instead of

```
<img src="../skins/monobook/ask_button.gif"/>
```